# Cannot reproduce dropdown menu in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

While getting into Bootstrap 3 i tried to make a simple dropdown menu just like here:http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Dropdown<b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything is fine, but nothing drops down! I wonder if i can fix that and how? Or maybe it is just a bug of Bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the order of defining scripts. First load Jquery script and then bootstrap.js

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68W9V/)

Comment: Exactly, this is the issue. Also never, ever, ever reference jquery-latest.js even in your development environment. You're asking for trouble @Nervosa